# Maven Base Command Line Behavior with Munit Tests in Anypoint Studio 7.16

Tags: maven, mule-studio, mulesoft, anypoint-studio, munit

I've encountered what seems to be an issue or perhaps a behavior in Anypoint Studio version 7.16. In the Windows -> Preferences -> Maven settings, the default Base command line for builds is:

```
mvn clean package -nsu -DskipMunitTests
```

Could someone please explain what this command means? Specifically, does it indicate that Munit checks are skipped during the build process, or are Munit tests still considered? I apologize if this question seems trivial; I simply want to ensure that Munit checks are not skipped while building and deploying the application locally. Notably, when using this Base command line, `mvn clean package -nsu -DskipMunitTests`, the application builds and deploys successfully.

However, when I remove `-DskipMunitTests` and keep the Base command line as `mvn clean package -nsu`, I encounter a build failure with the following error:

> Failed to execute goal
> com.mulesoft.munit.tols:munit-maven-plugin:2.3.11:test (test) on
> project xxx-yyy-zzz: Fail to create application structure:
> NullPointerException

Below is a snippet of my pom.xml file:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <app.runtime>4.4.0</app.runtime>
    <mule.maven.plugin.version>4.0.0</mule.maven.plugin.version>
    <munit.version>2.3.11</munit.version>
</properties>
```

What steps should I take to ensure successful builds and application deployment while disregarding `-DskipMunitTests`? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "What steps should I take to ensure successful builds" this is too broad a question. You should ask about specific issues.

Comment: Apologies for that. Specifically, what should be done to avoild NullPointerExecption while removing -DskipMunitTests? Anything to do with munit or maven plugin version? Or something else?

Answer (score 0):

```
Failed to execute goal com.mulesoft.munit.tols:munit-maven-plugin:2.3.11:test (test) on project xxx-yyy-zzz: Fail to create application structure: NullPointerException
```

This error may be caused by a corrupted workspace. Try cleaning the workspace or import the project into a newly created workspace.

You could also try updating to the [latest MUnit release](https://docs.mulesoft.com/release-notes/munit/munit-release-notes) in case there are fixes for this issue. The version you are using is from 2022. You could try also upgrading Mule to the latest release.

Unrelated to the issue, note that `-DskipMunitTests` means that MUnit tests are skipped when building. See the [documentation](https://docs.mulesoft.com/munit/latest/munit-maven-plugin#munit-maven-plugin-configuration-reference). This is the default configuration in Studio. That makes sense because when you are developing it will reduce the time to run or debug the application. Studio supports MUnit directly so you can execute the tests separately.

When you deploying the application outside Studio to a separate Mule runtime usually it is desirable to execute the tests as part of the build to ensure it is working correctly.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. If I understand correctly, -DskipMunitTests shouldn't be there as default if my application is to be deployed in let's say CloudHub 1.0. Because I want to make sure that with Munits, it builds fine locally as well. Is that a correct understanding? I understand that we can run Munits separately from src/test/munit (by running the Munit suite). Btw, I switched to a new workspace, upgraded Mule to latest release (Version: 7.16.0 Build Id: 202311081808), and used the latest version of munit version (3.1.0), but unfortunately gets the same error.

Comment: I'm realizing you are making two questions in one. Please split the question into two, one for the error and one for the skipMunitTests usage.